# Javascript POST array item

Tags: javascript, ejs

My only real question here is about posting to associative arrays and the syntax for putting them in a JSON database.

My Schema is contained under `user`, and has the following code:

```
person: [{plan: String}]
```

In my main input, I have this code to POST in the content. Just FYI, this specific instance is using React, though I don't imagine that's important:

```
<input name="plan" value={this.state.reactstate}/>
```

Now, in my routes, I have it set up like so:

```
if (req.body.plan) user.person.plan = req.body.plan;
```

This is called in my ejs file like so:

```
<ul>
<% for (var i = 0; i < user.person.length; i++){ %>
<li><%= user.person[i].plan %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

The goal is to have multiple 'plans' per person, which is why this is done as an array. The only problem I have now is getting my inputs into my DB. My arrangement works when I'm POST-ing single objects, but with array items my input field does nothing.

If I had instead done:

```
person: {type: String, default: ''}
```

My input field makes its POST request as it should. But not if I had it in the original example.

**EDIT**: I also wanted to clarify that my schema works. When I add dummy data like

```
person: [{"plan":"Go fishing" }, {"plan": "Go home"}]
```

directly into my JSON DB then my ejs view works exactly as I would expect. Thus, the only problem appears to be with how I put my data through my input form.

**EDIT** I will attempt to add a For Loop on my routes to see if that works.

I tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < user.history[i].length; i++){
if (req.body.stocklabel) user.history[i].stocklabel = req.body.stocklabel;}
```

which did not work.